# how to render 3D surfaces in Python

Tags: python

I currently have a working python code which generates a 2D animation of a colormap, in the shape of a circle.  This colormap is meant to represent the activation levels of the heart.
The next step is to take this 2D colormap and generate a 3D surface.
I would like to know what is the best and simplest way to do this in Python (keep in mind that the solution would have to be a free solution).  I have worked with Matplotlib and taken a look at the 3D surface rendering, however I find that it is not up to par, and thus I am looking for another solution.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try also Mayavi which is more centered on 3D visualizations.
Docs: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html
Installation: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html

For more detailed answers, you'll have to elaborate what you tried in Matplotlib and what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

[Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/) can help you to do this. If your 3D surface is in a circle, express your data in cylindrical function should be a good choice, then see [draw cylindrical function surface](https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/geometries/geometries.html#id6) section will help you to draw it into 3D space. To install Glass Engine, just use:

```
pip install glass-engine
```

See [full documentation](https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest).